# Typescript transpiles differently for build vs save

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, typescript2.0

I have an angular 1.6.x project being served up by a MVC project. When I hit save on any ts file, it transpiles my javascript as expected. When I build the site it transpiles the javascript into a different format from when I save.

On build, the angular modules are moved into an order which causes an angular $injector error.

How can I make build transpile method the same as the save transpile?

These are the typescript build settings within the MVC project properties:
[image: typescript build settings]

Comment: what is the config like for Release ? if you are publishing it generally uses Release mode config.

Comment: All configuration types are the same. I did say build and not publish, but you are correct in assuming it is an issue when publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every typescript file in your project there is a line in your proj file which looks like this:

`<TypeScriptCompile Include="app\app.ts" />`

Somehow my `app.ts` include was placed towards the bottom of the xml of my proj file. The build transpile method uses the order of your `TypeScriptCompile` include statements, whereas the transpile on save method is apparently a little more intelligent about re-ordering.

Life can move forward now...